How to replace WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for android 13 and above with READ_MEDIA_*
I have an Webview Android app developed in Android Studio for android 5.0(Lollipop) above, till android 12 all the permissions for media and files, pictures and video were working fine,
but now with Android 13 the dialog boxes for media and files permission is not showing as it mentions that we need to use READ_MEDIA_* (AUDIO.IMAGES,VIDEO) permissions for uploading and saving images, videos from the file manager
I have added the required permissions as mentioned in my manifest.xml file , here is my manifest file
 <!--INTERNET ACCESS PERMISSION-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--USER CAMERA PERMISSION-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <!--USER EXTERNAL STORAGE PERMISSION-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

But it still doesn't work , the permissions dialog box is not showing for images, videos and audios
Im also adding my **main activity.java **code file
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC=100;
    private static final String TEL_PREFIX = "tel:";
    private String userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType;
    String websiteURL = "https://portal.eduscol.in/?sc=MVMLKO"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;

    private boolean multiple_files = true;
    private static String file_type     = "*/*";
    private String cam_file_data = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> file_data;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> file_path;
    private final static int file_req_code = 1;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        //webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
            //webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request){
                    Log.d(TAG,"onPermissionRequest");
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, request.getOrigin().toString());
                            if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals("file:///")){
                                Log.d(TAG,"GRANTED");
                                request.grant(request.getResources());
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.d(TAG,"DENIED");
                                request.deny();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                /*-- handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+ --*/
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                    if (file_permission() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        file_path = filePathCallback;
                        Intent takePictureIntent = null;
                        Intent takeVideoIntent = null;

                        boolean includeVideo = false;
                        boolean includePhoto = false;

                        /*-- checking the accept parameter to determine which intent(s) to include --*/

                        paramCheck:
                        for (String acceptTypes : fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()) {
                            String[] splitTypes = acceptTypes.split(", ?+");
                            /*-- although it's an array, it still seems to be the whole value; split it out into chunks so that we can detect multiple values --*/
                            for (String acceptType : splitTypes) {
                                switch (acceptType) {
                                    case "*/*":
                                        includePhoto = true;
                                        includeVideo = true;
                                        break paramCheck;
                                    case "image/*":
                                        includePhoto = true;
                                        break;
                                    case "video/*":
                                        includeVideo = true;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes().length == 0) {

                            /*-- no `accept` parameter was specified, allow both photo and video --*/

                            includePhoto = true;
                            includeVideo = true;
                        }

                        if (includePhoto) {
                            takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                File photoFile = null;
                                try {
                                    photoFile = create_image();
                                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", cam_file_data);
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    //Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                                }
                                if (photoFile != null) {
                                    cam_file_data = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                                } else {
                                    cam_file_data = null;
                                    takePictureIntent = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (includeVideo) {
                            takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                File videoFile = null;
                                try {
                                    videoFile = create_video();
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    //Log.e(TAG, "Video file creation failed", ex);
                                }
                                if (videoFile != null) {
                                    cam_file_data = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
                                } else {
                                    cam_file_data = null;
                                    takeVideoIntent = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        contentSelectionIntent.setType(file_type);

                        if (multiple_files) {
                            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        }


                        Intent[] intentArray;
                        if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                        } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                        } else if (takeVideoIntent != null) {
                            intentArray = new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent};
                        } else {
                            intentArray = new Intent[0];
                        }

                        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File chooser");
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, file_req_code);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                                            String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                    MainActivity.this.websiteURL = url;
                    MainActivity.this.userAgent = userAgent;
                    MainActivity.this.contentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                    MainActivity.this.mimeType = mimeType;

                    String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC);
                    } else {
                        downloadFile();
                    }
//                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
//                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;

            /*-- if file request cancelled; exited camera. we need to send null value to make future attempts workable --*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                return;
            }

            /*-- continue if response is positive --*/
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(null == file_path){
                    return;
                }
                ClipData clipData;
                String stringData;

                try {
                    clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    stringData = intent.getDataString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    clipData = null;
                    stringData = null;
                }
                if (clipData == null && stringData == null && cam_file_data != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(cam_file_data)};
                }else{
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        final int numSelectedFiles = clipData.getItemCount();
                        results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            results[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Bitmap cam_photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            cam_photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                            stringData = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), cam_photo, null, null);
                        }catch (Exception ignored){}

                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(stringData)};
                    }
                }
            }

            file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            file_path = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == file_req_code){
                if(null == file_data) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                file_data.onReceiveValue(result);
                file_data = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public boolean file_permission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    private File create_image() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }

    private File create_video() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String file_name    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String new_name     = "file_"+file_name+"_";
        File sd_directory   = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".3gp", sd_directory);
    }

    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        /*public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX) || url.startsWith("sms:")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                *//*finish(intent);  ?????? *//*
                *//*onBackPressed();*//*
                webview.goBack();
                return false;
            }
            else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }*/

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            String url = uri.toString();
            //return handleUri(uri);
            if (url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX) || url.startsWith("sms:")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                /*finish(intent);  ?????? */
                /*onBackPressed();*/
                webview.goBack();
                return false;
            }
            else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "+ "document.querySelector('.row .col-md-3 .refresh .box-icon').style.display='none';"+"})()");
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webview.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void downloadFile() {
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(websiteURL));
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(websiteURL, contentDisposition, mimeType));

        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(websiteURL, contentDisposition, mimeType);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);

        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(websiteURL);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        dm.enqueue(request);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RC) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadFile();
            }
        }
    }

DO i need to do some changes in my mainactivity.java file also, im new to android webview i dont know what to handle here , please Guide

For Android 13+ you will only ask for the three READ_MEDIA_ permissions. And only when needed.

so no changes required in the MainActivity.java file ? And also what about downloadinf and uploading document file (.pdf,.xslx) in android 13 in a webview app

I did not look at your code. But i think you have to adapt it if it is old.

For uploading and downloading there are no permissions.
